# How to show featured page image as a link in home page (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Guys,

I have Static Home page in my Wordpress site. And have 4 pages with including featured image. Now I need to show those featured images inside my Home Page as like a link to these pages.

I created example image for you. Please visit to this link and get idea that I trying to tell. **[Visit Link][1]**

I'm waiting for you guys...

**[1]: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ngfyuzuw525zmbe/screen_pages.jpg**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the post or page thumbnail, see codex [get_the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

you can get the thumbnail of pages like below

```
 <?php query_posts('page_id=YOUR_PAGE_ID'); ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
         <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
   <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
   </a>
 <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

For the post thumbnail as link, you can do it by follows

Comment: hello if my answer is right, ticket it as right one

Comment: I know brother. Wait. I'm checking that.

Comment: is it worked? let me know asap

Comment: It's not working here

Comment: how you tried? put your code, the above code must get the featured image of the page, once you put the correct page id

Comment: @BigBroYesh up vote me, cheers, hope it is working to you

Comment: How do I vote up you?

Comment: you can see the up and down arrows above the tick mark, you can upvote by uparrow

Comment: Oh! I haven't reputation for that. I have only 12